# Forwarding a MultiPart File Upload Request through Multiple Play Applications

Tags: java, json, file-upload, playframework, websocket

I have **two Play applications (say A and B) and a browser client (C)**. The aim is to send a file and some json data using `multipart/form-data`, from the client C to B via A. So the process is **C -> A -> B**.

From the client the data comes in the form of a multipart with headers like -

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWnmuXaBXoBUSKF92
```

My Request Payload looks like -

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryWnmuXaBXoBUSKF92
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

{"abc": 1, "bcd": 2, "xyz": 3}
------WebKitFormBoundaryWnmuXaBXoBUSKF92
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test3.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv


------WebKitFormBoundaryWnmuXaBXoBUSKF92--
```

Thus I am sending the json and the file together in a single **POST** request.

Now I wish that this content be forwarded to the Play app **B** after going through the Play app **A**.

I have tried three ways -

1. Parsing the multipart/form-data on **A** using `MultipartFormData`, and taking out the `File` and the `json`. In this approach, I am trying to regenerate the request for the Play App **B**. Now I am stuck on the forwarding part.I read [this](https://nebojsaristin.wordpress.com/2014/05/27/creating-multipart-form-data-post-requests-using-play-framework/) but I am not sure how to use it with files. Help needed here.
2. Second method I tried using `websocket`. Here was sending the file as a `bytestream`, fixing a framesize and slicing the file before sending. Here the problem I face is maintaining the frames in sync, since the `send()` is async. I tried implementing a solution where the server sends an `ACK` when it receives a chunk of the file and this loops on till `eof`. This method will work, though I am not sure if its the best solution.
3. A stream based solution might be possible. But I have no idea how to implement this in Java(Purely!). The Play Docs didn't provide much help. This method will be better than the first one because it will prevent us from downloading the file as a temp file, and will be faster.

I want to know what is the best way to solve this problem. Any other way is also welcome!

I am using Play 2.3.6 (Java). Sorry for the long read.